# Filter and get unique values from array

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to apply filter on array and get unique values. In the array below, I am applying filter on `Group` and then extract unique values from `Category`. I have written a function which is working absolutely fine, wanted to understand if it is an efficient approach to pull unique values after filtering.

```js
var myList = [
    { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Equity", "Category": "ABCD", "Category Rank": 1 },
    { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Debt", "Category": "Credit Risk", "Category Rank": 1 },
    { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Equity", "Category": "XYZ", "Category Rank": 1 },
    { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Equity", "Category": "XYZ", "Category Rank": 1 }
]


function getUnique(myList, searchTerm) {

    // Filtering on 'Group' variable;   
    var data_filter = myList.filter(element => element.Group == searchTerm);

    // Get values of CategoryList;
    var CategoryList = [];
    data_filter.forEach(item => {
        a = item.Category;
        CategoryList.push(a);
    });

    // Unique values of CategoryList and then sort;
    var newarr = CategoryList.filter((x, y) => CategoryList.indexOf(x) == y).sort();

    return (newarr);

}

console.log(getUnique(myList, "Equity"))
```

Comment: There's no JSON anywhere in your code. JSON is a text format. What you have there is simply an array of objects, in literal form. Shorter version: https://jsfiddle.net/oLwj5vu8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Your filter logic to filter down the input array is correct. In order to generate the unique categories, you could create an array of categories using `Array.map`. From that list you can pick the unique elements using `Set`. Also sort that unique array if needed.

**Working Fiddle**

```js
var myList = [
  { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Equity", "Category": "ABCD", "Category Rank": 1 },
  { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Debt", "Category": "Credit Risk", "Category Rank": 1 },
  { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Equity", "Category": "XYZ", "Category Rank": 1 },
  { "Fund": "Baroda Credit Risk Fund Plan B Direct Growth", "Group": "Equity", "Category": "XYZ", "Category Rank": 1 }];

function getUnique(myList, searchTerm) {
  // Filtering on 'Group' variable;   
  const data_filter = myList.filter(element => element.Group == searchTerm);
  const CategoryList = [...new Set(data_filter.map(item => item.Category))];
  return CategoryList.sort();
}

console.log(getUnique(myList, "Equity"));
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates before posting answers.